# Is there a way that we can use Banno's apis to direct deposit cash into an account?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

We're building a product that helps move cash between accounts. How could we accomplish this in Banno?

Would Transfers work at all?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited] The Banno Digital Toolkit doesn’t have APIs available to do the transfers themselves.

However, it’s possible to get the unmasked account number via a specific [account number API endpoint](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/) so that would probably work for your use case.

Alternatively, you could use [jXchange's REST or SOAP APIs](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For jXchange, the transfer (XferAdd) behavior includes error checking that both the from and to accounts are the same customer. If that is not the use case, then a pair of TrnAdd are used instead.