# Is there an API that will allow me to transfer funds between a user's checking and savings accounts?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

**Question:**
Is there an API endpoint that exists that will allow me to transfer funds between a user's checking account and savings account?

**Context:**
I was looking at the API reference and saw the external funds transfer API. But after further inspection I did not see anything regarding internal funds transfer.

https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transfers/external-transfer-accounts/#/

Also I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892504/is-there-a-way-that-we-can-use-bannos-apis-to-direct-deposit-cash-into-an-accou) was asked over a year ago. Have the internal transfer API's been implemented since then?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to do transfers via the Banno Digital Toolkit.

The alternatives of jXchange/SymXchange are your best bets.

Comment: Understood. Is there any plan for these API's on the roadmap?

Comment: Nothing on the 12-month roadmap as of this writing. We highly recommend registering for the monthly "Digital Banking Meetup" where the roadmap is shared. Registration links are posted each month at https://www.jackhenry.com/resources/events